# Delete where date is 30 days back from now SQL Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Hello Im trying to delete all the records from my table which are 30 days old from now.

The date is saved as `TIMESTAMP` as `YYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

My table:

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_GYM_MESSAGES + " ("                    
            + COLUMN_MAIN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + COLUMN_MESSAGE + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_MESSAGE_DATE + " TIMESTAMP, "
            + COLUMN_SENDER + " TEXT);");
```

In my code I use this:

```
String whereClause = COLUMN_MESSAGE_DATE +" < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY)";

ourDatabase.delete(TABLE_GYM_MESSAGES, whereClause, null);
```

The error i get:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "30": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM gym_message_table WHERE gym_message_date < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Check this out: [http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html]. It has what you need.

Comment: This select should do the trick: `SELECT date('now', '-30 day')`